Proving that Convexity approx. equals Duration squared but something goes wrong?
I am trying to derive a formula for bond convexity that I saw in a textbook which states that
$$\text{convexity} = \frac{\text{Macaulay duration}^2 + \text{Macaulay duration} + \text{dispersion}}{(1+\text{periodic IRR})^2}.$$
I am assuming that a bond portfolio's IRR is continuously compounded, IRR denoted as $y$, and that the bond portfolio value is a function of its IRR, denoted $V(y)$. Modified Duration and Convexity are defined as
$$\text{ModD}(y)= -\frac{1}{V(y)}\frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y}$$
$$\text{C}(y)=\frac{1}{V(y)}\frac{\partial ^2 V(y)}{\partial y^2}.$$
I then start with the $C(y)V(y)$ with the goal of getting something that looks similar to the first expression (just with $\text{ModD}$ instead of $\text{Macaulay Duration}$). This is my work, however, it leads me to an obviously wrong result but I am not sure where is/are the mistake/s.
$$C(y)V(y)=\frac{\partial ^2 V(y)}{\partial y^2}$$
$$C(y)V(y)=\frac{\partial  \left( -V(y) \text{ModD}(y) \right)}{\partial y}$$
$$C(y)V(y)=-\frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y}\times \text{ModD}(y)-V(y)\times \frac{\partial (\text{ModD}(y))}{\partial y} $$
$$C(y)=-\frac{1}{V(y)}\frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y}\times \text{ModD}(y)-\frac{\partial (\text{ModD}(y))}{\partial y}$$
$$C(y)=\left( \text{ModD}(y) \right)^2-\frac{\partial (- \frac{1}{V(y)}\frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y} )}{\partial y}$$
$$C(y)=\left( \text{ModD}(y) \right)^2-\left( \frac{1}{\left(  V(y)\right)^2} \times \frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y }  - \frac{1}{V(y)} \times \frac{\partial ^2 V(y)}{\partial y ^2}\right)$$
$$C(y)=\left( \text{ModD}(y) \right)^2- \frac{1}{  V(y)} \times \frac{1}{V(y)} \frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y }  + C(y)$$
$$C(y)=\left( \text{ModD}(y) \right)^2+ \frac{1}{  V(y)} \times \text{ModD}(y)  + C(y)$$
$$\left( \text{ModD}(y) \right)^2+ \frac{1}{  V(y)} \times \text{ModD}(y)  =0$$
$$\text{ModD}(y)\left( \text{ModD}(y) + \frac{1}{  V(y)} \right)  =0$$
I end up with
$$\text{ModD}(y)=-\frac{1}{V(y)}$$
which is obviously wrong. Where am I going  wrong?

I believe the formula may have been derived in an article: Bond Portfolio Duration, Cash Flow Dispersion and Convexity by Donald J. Smith, 2010 which is available online. Frankly I have not checked the math carefully, but see Equation 9 in the paper on page 1670 and also the Appendix at the end.

One error is that:
$$C(y)=\left( \text{ModD}(y) \right)^2-\left( \frac{1}{\left(  V(y)\right)^2} \times \frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y }  - \frac{1}{V(y)} \times \frac{\partial ^2 V(y)}{\partial y ^2}\right)$$
should be:
$$C(y)=\left( \text{ModD}(y) \right)^2-\left( \frac{1}{\left(  V(y)\right)^2} \times \left ( \frac{\partial V(y)}{\partial y } \right )^2  - \frac{1}{V(y)} \times \frac{\partial ^2 V(y)}{\partial y ^2}\right)$$
